# set schedule in android

Tags: android, timer, schedule

I want to set a schedule in my application.
If my application is stopped by the application task killer, my application automatically runs after many seconds after it gets killed.

My application is like this :

```
public class AlarmServiceDemo extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startalarm);
        Button buttonCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelalarm);

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {

            // @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(AlarmServiceDemo.this, MyAlarmService.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmServiceDemo.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

            Toast.makeText(AlarmServiceDemo.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {

            //@Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

                // Tell the user about what we did.
                Toast.makeText(AlarmServiceDemo.this, "Cancel!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is my service :

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onUnbind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
}
```

But my schedule doesn't work. How can I solved it?

Comment: Did you mention your service in the manifest?

Comment: i have mention my service in manifest..i got warning like this `05-15 10:30:02.197: WARN/ActivityManager(69): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.exercise.AndroidAlarmService/.MyAlarmService in 5000ms
` what it's??thank you @Rasel

Comment: Seems like your service is working and you are getting this warning because service is starting again after crashing

Comment: but seems like my application doesn't running again after force close..or force close is special case??@Rasel

Comment: So write the code in the onStart method of service to start your application.

Comment: what code to write in the onStart method of my service??thank you and sorry for bother you @Rasel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write exactly what you mean by starting application.If you want to start an Activity then you can write

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context,
                AlarmServiceDemo.class);
        activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(activityIntent);

 super.onStart(intent, startId);

}
```

Comment: this is keep running after the application get force close in many seconds??i try to force close my application and wait..but my application doesn't run automatically..thank you @Rasel

Comment: what you are trying to do?suppose you scheduled your service to start after 10 minutes and then force close your app.So after 10 minutes when your service get started it will fire the intent of AlarmServiceDemo.So you will see that screen on top

Comment: if my application get force close, i want my application automatic running without open before..something like that :)